# H2 DB syntax creating table

Tags: java, spring, h2

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used :

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

but I have this error generating an embedded H2 DB:

```
Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [db/schema.sql]: 

CREATE TABLE t_user ( id bigint PRIMARY KEY, 
                       company_id bigint(20) , 
                       FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES public.t_company(id)); nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (
```

The full error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDeviceEventRepository' defined in file [/Users/nunito/Development/J2EE/eclipseWSJ2EE/tdk-cloud/target/classes/com/tdk/iot/service/JdbcDeviceEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/tdk/iot/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [db/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE t_user ( id bigint PRIMARY KEY, company_id bigint(20) , FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES public.t_company(id)); nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
    at com.ideefecloud.iot.IdeefeCloudApplication.main(IdeefeCloudApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/ideefecloud/iot/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [db/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE t_user ( id bigint PRIMARY KEY, company_id bigint(20) , FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES public.t_company(id)); nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [db/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE t_user ( id bigint PRIMARY KEY, company_id bigint(20) , FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES public.t_company(id)); nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of class path resource [db/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE t_user ( id bigint PRIMARY KEY, company_id bigint(20) , FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES public.t_company(id)); nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:492) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:238) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.initDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:196) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.getDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.build(EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.java:270) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ideefecloud.iot.config.PersistenceConfig.dataSource(PersistenceConfig.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ideefecloud.iot.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e89c34fc.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ideefecloud.iot.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e89c34fc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$581d73ff.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ideefecloud.iot.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e89c34fc.dataSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:471) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: (
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.readTableContentsSource(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.compileCreateTableBody(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.compileCreateTable(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreate(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

Comment: what is the full exception for the sql syntax error

Comment: Please enter the code in Java?

Comment: SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (